# Picasso not displaying images in GridView

Tags: java, android

I've read several posts having similar problems yet I still can't make the fix.
The app I'm trying to build is supposed to retrieve images from a link and display them. This is done through Picasso and is supposed to be displayed in GridView format.

Here is my MovieAdapter.java:

```
    package com.example.android.popularmovies.utilities;

    import android.app.Activity;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import com.example.android.popularmovies.R;
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    /**
     * Created by Jonathan on 6/18/2017.
     */

    public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
        Context mContext;
        int mLayoutResourceId;
        ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<>();

    public MovieAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                                 ArrayList<String> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        mLayoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        mContext = context;
        mData = data;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<String> mGridData) {
        mData=mGridData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //TODO code is working. Posters arent displayed :(
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_moviePoster);
        convertView.setTag(image);
        try {
            String poster = NetworkUtils.posterBuilder(mData.get(position));

            Picasso.with(mContext).
                    load(poster).
                    into(image);
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

When running the code, nothing is displayed. Please help and thank you

Update
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_moviePoster"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/gv_movieData"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnWidth="100dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_loadingBar"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Return convertView not image inside getView

Comment: I did as you suggested, but there's still no change in the display. Could it be my XML file?

Comment: Do you have an xml that you use to inflate the convertView?

Comment: Also have you included the relevant permissions?

Comment: I just updated the post with the xml used as well as the permission

Comment: It seems that inside a gridview you want to implement an imageView besides a progress bar? Like a custom gridView!

Comment: The progress bar is supposed to be displayed while the Adapter retrieves the data, then disappears after the data is retrieved and ready to be displayed. This is handled in the MainActivity.java

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding things a bit. First off, "while the adapter retrieves data"... adapter shall retrieve data for individual posters, because no where I can see that it is retrieving data except that String poster part. What you actually want your grid view should look like? A gridView that has images and a progress bar beneath it or something else? Is the adapter working/

Comment: As far as I can see, the Adapter faces no bugs or errors reported by logcat. Picasso is supposed to load the images into the gridView as shown. The progress bar is to be shown while the posters are being retrieved and loaded into the gridView, and then disappears when the posters are being displayed.

Comment: Okay, buddy you are actually making a custom gridView. For custom gridViews you need to have an xml that will represent an individual customized grid element (ImageView + progress bar) and then you have to populate the main xml that contains the gridview with this individual element xml. https://caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html See this for example.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the clarification! It is greatly appreciated :]